# Why does my heroku app not appear on google search results

Tags: django, heroku, google-search-console

I have deployed my django project on heroku. I can access my it via my domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and I have comfirmed domain ownership on google search console.I have provided sitemaps on google search console and requested indexing. Its been about two days and i can not see my website on google search results. I have also tried using site:my_domain.com but still cannot find any results

Referring page None detected
Crawl
Last crawl
12 Jan 2021, 14:26:31
Crawled as
Googlebot smartphone
Crawl allowed?
Yes
Page fetch
Successful
Indexing allowed?
Yes
Indexing
User-declared canonical
None
Google-selected canonical

Inspected URL

Comment: It can easily take a week, or longer. Patience is probably the answer. This website mentions between 4 days and 4 weeks: https://www.theleverageway.com/blog/how-long-does-it-take-google-to-index-a-new-site/#:~:text=It%20takes%20between%204%20days,in%20less%20than%204%20days.

Comment: @MURSTE I suggest you to also ask this to [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @user3184950 Patience was the answer..Thank you